# Resolving terraform state issues where state has suspended AWS account resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

At #dayjob another team suspended some old AWS accounts where I had terraform provisioned resources. Now while trying to remove the resources from the existing configurations, due to the accounts being suspended, I am getting the following error:

```
│ Error: configuring Terraform AWS Provider: IAM Role 
(arn:aws:iam::0000000000:role/ARoleWouldGoHere) cannot be assumed.
│
│ There are a number of possible causes of this - the most common are:
│   * The credentials used in order to assume the role are invalid
│   * The credentials do not have appropriate permission to assume the role
│   * The role ARN is not valid
│
│ AWS Error: operation error STS: AssumeRole, https response error StatusCode: 403, 
RequestID: 74a8bfc1-aa65-4be9-b6cf-2a052bc5c4c9, api error AccessDenied: User: 
arn:aws:iam::00000000:user/my@iamuseraccount.aws is not authorized to 
perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: 
arn:aws:iam::00000000:role/ARoleWouldGoHere
│
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].Stage,
│   on providers.tf line 93, in provider "aws":
│   93: provider "aws" {
```

Since the account was suspended and terraform cannot attempt to assume a role in the suspended account to then deprovision the resources, how do I fix the Terraform state? Thank you!

Comment: Does `terraform state list` work?

Answer (score 0):

If you no longer intend to manage those resources through terraform, you can use 'terraform state rm [resource-name]' to remove those resources from your state file. But this is assuming that you have several accounts/profiles in use, and you are only removing resources related to the suspended account.